# How to make a Regex for AWS resource

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want a regex that will match the following AWS resources:

- instanceId (i-XXXXXX)
- spotRequestId (sir-XXXX)
- imageId (ami-XXXX)
- volumeId (vol-XXXXX)
- snapshotId (snap-XXXX)
- privateIP (123.231.231.231)

In addition, I want the regex to be able to match a list of resources in the following format:

```
resourceId, resourceId, ....
```

The list is not mandatory and the spaces between the ids aren't mandatory either.

Here is what I've tried:

```
(((i|sir|ami|snap|vol|ssi)-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))+ *,* *
```

Comment: `\b(?:(?:i|sir|ami|snap|vol|ssi|Ipv4)\b(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s*,\s*(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})*)\b` Try https://regex101.com/r/VNRgty/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Almost perfect! but I need a full match (including the separating commas and optional spaces between each resource

Comment: Can you edit the link https://regex101.com/r/VNRgty/1 and add the examples that should match? What do you mean by full match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Sure, the link is https://regex101.com/r/RyGE0l/1. A full match means that I also need the commas and the spaces to be colored

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/U0Mx4C/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:(?:i|sir|ami|snap|vol|ssi|Ipv4)(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\b|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(?:\s*,\s*(?:(?:i|sir|ami|snap|vol|ssi|Ipv4)(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\b|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))*$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:i|sir|ami|snap|vol|ssi|Ipv4)` Match 1 of the alternatives
  - `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\b` Optionally match a `-` and 1+ times any of the listed
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` Match 4 times 1-3 digits separated by a `.`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s*,\s*` Match a comma between optional whitespace chars
  - `(?:(?:i|sir|ami|snap|vol|ssi|Ipv4)(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\b|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})` The same pattern as in the first part
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PD2E8Y/1)

Comment: AWS ids are hexadecimal strings. So, the bit after i-, ami-, etc is [a-f0-9]+